# Best way to broadcast camera in real-time

Tags: webrtc, real-time, broadcast

I am trying to find the best way to broadcast a camara and send the stream to 200 connections.

If I use **web-rtc**, I am limited with the CPU power. I've tried to use a server as a gateway, but the number connection maximum I can perform is 60. And 120 with 2 servers.

I can't use web socket to send stream because, the TCP protocol create latency.

Last solution : use RTMP protocol, but there is 5s-10s of latency.

My question: Is there a solution to stream a camera to many clients (200/300)  in real-time  ?

Comment: What's the reason for requiring low latency?  Things get a lot more expensive this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using webrtc would not work as I assume the device the the camera will need a huge bandwidth. The best way is to use an SFU. This will send the video to to the server to then broadcast it to every peer. It is normally able to handle 200 connections if only video is used.

I've implemented such a server using [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/). It also allows you to balance the load over several cpu's and multiple servers.

Here is a [simple project](https://github.com/mkhahani/mediasoup-sample-app) where this library is used. 
There are also other solutions like Janus gateway or kurento server. Although I haven't used them.

SECOND SOLUTION

I found [This github repository](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast) which allows video forwarding peer to peer even for large audiences. Basically forwarding the stream to other peers which will also forward their received stream. I assume that there will be a little more latency as the video could be relayed through many peers.

Comment: I also made my own implementation as a multi-user room with audio/video using mediasoup here: [github repository](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-video-rooms)